# Regression model to predict an individual's race

Tags: regression, predictive-models, logit, beta-regression

I have a database of individuals containing data about *age*, *gender*, *place of living* (census tract level) and *income* but nothing about *race*.

Beside this, I have aggregate race data at census tract level, including percentage of white/non-white along with data about average income, proportion of gender and average age of residences in the census tracts.

Can I somehow use the later database to predict race for each individual?

Comment: While classification can be a special case of regression most of the time, I would not call it a regression problem. I think its a classification problem. Why not google multivariate classification?

Comment: @theGD you're missing the main feature of the problem -- they outcome is only observed at the aggregate level

Comment: You won't be able to make well-constrained predictions, but you will be able to constrain your prediction somewhat.  Like, rather than the probability for an individual equaling the proportion in the census district, you'll be able to use the other data to improve on that naive estimate.  But probably not all that much.  I'm actually not totally sure how you'd go about this, but I think that it'd probably involve entropy-based methods.  These wouldn't be worthwhile if vague predictions aren't helpful to you.

Comment: Even if you build the model how would you test its performance? Forget about this

Comment: @Aksakal so you are suggesting there is no way to predict individual's race?

Comment: I wonder if this can be done with a finite mixture model where the census tract level are used to model the component probabilities.

Comment: @DimitriyV.Masterov Thanks, I'll google finite mixture model.